# class name for asp input box

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm a asp beginner but familiar in php.I used class for defining css in asp as two ways.I want to know which is the best way  practice to use.

```
 Way I
    <asp:textbox runat="server" class="sample" id="text1"></asp:textbox>

 Way II
  <asp:textbox runat="server" CssClass="sample" id="text1"></asp:textbox>
```

Both is working for  css style as

```
.sample{
   /*some style*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Way II incase asp controls and Way I incase of Html controls.
Incase of asp controls if you want to change the class based on some logic, you could in the code behind(webforms) if you are doing Way II.